# How do I create a printRow function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following function in Haskell:

```
printRow :: [(Int, String)] → String
```

I want it, given a list of pairs (the left element
giving the desired length of a field and the right element its contents), to format one row in a table. For example,

```
printRow [ (5, "Alice"),(6, "Allen"),(6, "female"),(6, "82000")]
```

should return the formatted row

```
"|Alice|Allen |female| 82000|"
```

I know that I should probably use the functions `intercalate`, `map` and `uncurry`, but I'm a bit stuck, as I'm not very familiar with functional programming. I've tried something in the likes of:

```
printRow (int, string) =  if all isDigit string
                          -- all_digits should be right-aligned
    then ...
    else map intercalate "|" uncurry (int, string)
```

As you can probably guess, this won't work, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Start by separating `printRow` (which takes a list) from `printCell` (which takes a width and a string). You don't necessarily need `uncurry` - writing the functions with explicit parameters and pattern matching will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing how to handle *one* formatting specification,

```
printOne :: (Int, String) -> String
printOne (int, string) =
   if all isDigit string 
      then  a ++ b ++ "|"
      else  b ++ a ++ "|"
    where
       a = ....
       b = ....
       c = length string
```

we can turn *each* specification in a list into a formatted string, with *`map`*, and concatenate the results

```
printRow specs = a ++ concat ( map printOne specs )
  where
  a = ....
```

You should be able to complete the code. To repeatedly output a space character, use [`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've chosen a = replicate (int - c) "  " and b = string for the printOne variables, and didn't figure out what to fill in for a at printRow. Could you please help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: try `a = ""` and see if the output is what you wanted, and if not, how to make it so. :)